# Query handling on no connection to database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose we have a condition in which we have many clients are running the same windows application and using the same database, but net connectivity is not good in that region so it wont be able to access the database server all the time. Can we store SQL queries during this time and then execute them later?

And also how we will maintain data consistency for all the clients in this situation?

Comment: i am currently using local database server only

Comment: Local which dbms server? MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc?

Comment: i am currently using mysql  server

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that environment.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we store SQL queries during this time and then execute them later?

You could, but it might not be the best way. I recommend solving this not on the data access layer, but rather in the business logic. So instead of storing a sql statement to be executed later, I would rather store objects that represent the business action that should be performed.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little more. I mean i am not able to make out what you are saying